# How to set! value of an object in a function?

Tags: racket

I don't understand why when I use this function called m-add on an empty list, the list stays unchanged. When I copy the exact function concent with parameters, the list is changed. Why it doesn't work in a function?

````
(define (m-add x v m)
  (set! m (cons (mcons x v) m)))

```with for example this

> (define n null)
> (m-add 'q 3 n)

```result:

> n
'()

``but this:

> (set! n (cons (mcons 'q 3) n))

``gives result:

> n
(list (mcons 'q 3))
````

Comment: Relevant documentation: [_Objects and Imperative Update_](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._.Objects_and_.Imperative_.Update%29), [_Procedure Applications and Local Variables_](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._.Procedure_.Applications_and_.Local_.Variables%29). In Racket, functions are _call-by-value_ (not _call-by-reference_) which means when you pass `n` as an argument, it gets evaluated. Only the value gets passed in, not a reference that can be mutated. You can get around this by using a value that is a reference, such as a box.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is quite simple: in the first sample code you're reassigning a procedure *parameter* (a *local* reference to the list) to a new value, but the list "outside" still points to the original value and when the procedure exits, that reference remains unchanged.

If you want to modify the list "outside", you need to modify a reference to that list, not to a parameter. Just be aware that this is not functional programming, and in Scheme we wouldn't normally do things like this:

```
(define lst null)

(define (m-add x v)
  (set! lst (mcons (mcons x v) lst)))

(m-add 'q 3)

lst
=> (mcons (mcons 'q 3) '())
```